# Downloading .csv file from website using .bat or xslt 2.0

Tags: csv, batch-file, xslt-2.0, download

I am trying to download a `.csv` file from [a website](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/inflationandpriceindices/timeseries/chaw/mm23) using a `.bat` file in the current folder *(or specified)*.

I think there is some issue with how the download works for this `.csv` file; I think it downloads only on button/tab click.

If you scroll down there is the option - Download this time series and green color tab `.csv` with the following uri:

```
https://www.ons.gov.uk/generator?format=csv&amp;uri=/economy/inflationandpriceindices/timeseries/chaw/mm23
```

This is my `.bat` file content:

```
@echo off
SET "FILENAME=%~dp0\series.csv"
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "JobName" https://www.ons.gov.uk/generator?format=csv&amp;uri=/economy/inflationandpriceindices/timeseries/chaw/mm23 "%FILENAME%"
```

I have even tried to do this using `XSLT 2.0`, but I was unable to automate this download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with batch and I think powershell is much better tool for this job in terms of long time support and easiness. Here is very sample script to download file by given link

```
$url = "https://www.ons.gov.uk/generator?format=csv&uri=/economy/inflationandpriceindices/timeseries/chaw/mm23"
$output = "$PSScriptRoot\series.csv"
$start_time = Get-Date

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```

Create sample file with script named like download.ps1.
You'll need to cd to file directory and run it like `.\download.ps1`

Comment: Thanks . It worked and downloaded file . but is there is way to schedule it run on windows daily so that it automatically downloads this file daily at specified location?

Comment: I think you can use default windows task scheduler to run it daily or using any trigger you want. There are a lot of articles about this like https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/11/weekend-scripter-use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script/

Comment: @Khushi, scheduling this is outside of the scope of your question and as such, should you have difficulty in implementing it, you should start a new question directed to the appropriate audience.

Comment: @Compo: sure . Thanks